# Python: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to load an image to the array. Then I want to show it by pyplot. The problem is somewhere in between.

I tried different types of imread. I got to install only the one from pyplot which my cause problem.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread

images = []
img = imread('1.png')
img = np.array(img.resize(224,224))
images.append(img)

images_arr = np.asarray(images)
images_arr = images_arr.astype('float32')

plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
curr_img = np.reshape(images_arr[0], (224,224))
plt.imshow(curr_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

There is the error:

```
images_arr = images_arr.astype('float32')
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`img.resize()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) resizes your data *in place* and returns `None`. Don't use the return value to create an array, just use `img` directly. It's a numpy array *already*:

```
img = imread('1.png')
img.resize(224,224)  # alters the array in-place, returns None
images.append(img)   # so just use the array directly.
```

If you wanted a copy of the data, resized, use [`numpy.resize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html#numpy.resize)`:

```
img = imread('1.png')
resized_img = np.resize(img, (224,224))
images.append(resized_img)
```

Note that the `matplotlib.pyplot.imread()` function is nothing more than an alias for   [`matplotlib.image.imread()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread).